# Simulating fluid dynamics for Generative Design of water turbine in Autodesk Fusion 360

Tags: fluid-mechanics, simulation, computer-aided-design, autodesk-inventor

I am trying to use Autodesk Fusion 360's generative design feature to produce more efficient turbine blades for hydroelectric power generators.

How can I simulate the load of water-fall on a turbine and use it to optimize the shape of the turbine? Also where can i obtain a starting shape model of a turbine?

Comment: Brunel did the design of the propellor for the SS Great Britain by hand - where are you starting?

Comment: You start the same way as any textbook will explain. Match up the desired flow rate, RPM, power or torque, and the blade inlet and outlet angles. All that is basically just Newton's laws of motion and 3D geometry. Then you can start tweaking the shape of the blades between the leading and trailing edges for efficiency, if you want.